# Numpy matrix get set of elements keys in another array

Tags: python, numpy

I have following numpy matrix(value_matrix).

```
[[0.3,0.5,1,0.2,0.9,0.5,0.6,0.3,0.7,0.8]
 [0.9,0.6,0.1,0.4,0.2,0.7,0.6,0.9,0.5,0.4]]
```

I need to get elements from each row (inside a loop) where the column number(index) is inside another numpy array.

ex: `key_array -> [2,0,1,3]`

ex: `value_matrix.item(0,key_array)` kind of retrieval method.

How can I do this with numpy?

Comment: Not clear - Which ones are the inputs, what's the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, you need something like this:

```
mat = np.matrix([[0.3,0.5,1,0.2,0.9,0.5,0.6,0.3,0.7,0.8],[0.9,0.6,0.1,0.4,0.2,0.7,0.6,0.9,0.5,0.4]]) 
key_array =  [2,0,1,3]
for i in range(len(mat)):
    print(mat[i,key_array])
# result
# [[ 1.   0.3  0.5  0.2]]
# [[ 0.1  0.9  0.6  0.4]]
```

However, as @Divakar says, your question is not clear enough.